# Is there a TTL for MySQL as there is in MongoDB?

Tags: mysql

In MongoDB there is expireAfterSeconds index which deletes the object automatically after a certain amount of time. I was wondering if there is such a thing in MySQL?

[MongoDB docs about expiring data](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, you need to `DELETE` the data when it's expired.

You can implement something similar by adding a DATETIME field and run a scheduled task in your operating system (a cronjob on Unix-like systems).

You can even schedule it directly in MySQL:

- [MySQL Manual: Using the Event Scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/events.html)
- [Stack Overflow: how to schedule an mysql query?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9621355/238978)

Comment: In some newer MySQL versions you will be able to schedule events, see this anwser; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19197486/mysql-record-that-would-subject-to-ttl/19400466#comment54034258_19400466

Comment: the first link is 404