# PHP store some data in mySQL for x hours (limited time)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

How is it possible to store data in the database for a limited time (like for example 1 hour)?

A user searches a certain thing, the logic is executed server-side and the search result is loaded. As the result is loaded, I want to store it in MySQL and keep it only x hours. After x hours this data should be deleted from the database.

How is it possible to do this in Laravel or in PHP (It does not matter for me. I just mentioned about Laravel as it may have some libraries for this)? Is it about writing logic in SQL or it's a PHP task?

How to do this? Any suggestions/links/solutions?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you just give each row a timestamp? Then query by rows that were added less than `X` hours ago?  Does that data really need to be removed?

Comment: Yes. I need this data removed. This means that I have asynchronously to make every second request to the database and to check the diff in time?

Comment: consider a dedicated cache, like redis or memcached, rather than a temporary table. They have expire properties that will automatically do this. But as noted by @axlj you can just use a timestamp field and a procedure to delete rows on a schedule.

Comment: It is my task to keep the data in the database, and I need it to be only for some hours

Comment: @Rafael do you mean this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-overview.html?

Comment: Yes, that is it.

Comment: thank you all very much! post it as an answer and I will mark it as accepted

Comment: @AndrewT you should answer your question in a couple days with the solution you arrived to.

Comment: Thank you! I will continue the work tomorrow and I will post the solution here when I arrive to it!

Comment: Don't use MySQL as a caching system, there are plenty of *actual* caching systems that are far better. eg: Redis.

Comment: Just for curiosity for one hour you can store data in Redis instead of mysql why do you even bother?

Comment: Seems a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19197486/mysql-record-that-would-subject-to-ttl

Answer (score 1):

> Is it about writing logic in SQL or it's a PHP task?

Doing this with `php` would be a hassle because you would always need to send requests to check if a record is expired and then send another to delete. This can be achieved using `events` in `mysql`. [I came across this blog post which might be helpful](http://mrjoelkemp.com/2011/04/mysql-event-to-remove-expired-data/).

Also dont forget to check the `mysql` [documentation page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-overview.html)

Answer (score 1):

Tag records with an expiration timestamp, and have a cron job run every minute (or whatever frequency you prefer) to delete expired records.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for this task would be to use the Redis database. There are 2 drivers for PHP: **pRedis** and **phpRedis**.

The **pRedis** is a implementation written in PHP which works relatively very slow for a big number of users.

The **phpRedis** driver is written in C, and it works much faster.

Use the **$redis->psetex($key, $destroy_time, $value)** function to create self-destroying records. Hope it helps anyone in future