# Best way to remove entries from table after x days mySQL Workbench and express js (node)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I am trying to come up with a way to delete entries that are x days old. Right now, every new entry has a time stamp by doing the following in the row default:

Column name: created, Not Null
and on the default section I have

```
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

So I was wondering what Delete query i could use in my app.connection to delete entries that are 2 days old. It is a bit confusing because it provides seconds, as I initially thought I could just get the current data-2 and delete all entries older than that.

Thanks

Comment: Well there are `86400` seconds in a day . "It provides seconds" probably means it's returning an Epoch. So two days ago would be `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - (86400 * 2)`

Comment: It's great when systems make up there own time integers: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now

Comment: Or just 172800.

Answer (score 0):

You could use MySQL's event scheduler to run delete queries and clear 2 days old records.

Check this post
[MySQL record that would subject to TTL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19197486/mysql-record-that-would-subject-to-ttl/19400466)