# Delete from all tables within a database where X

Tags: mysql, sql

Within my database I have a large number of tables which contain dates, expiry dates to be precise.

Currently I perform the following commands to remove any rows which are older than a date using:

```
 DELETE FROM tablename WHERE DATE(datepoint) < '2019-03-12'
```

1) Is there a way I can instead search and delete from an entire database?

```
DELETE FROM database WHERE DATE(datepoint) < '2019-03-12'
```

2) Following this, is there a automated script I could which does this action on a daily basis? Rather than manually?

Kind Regards,

Shyam

Comment: Break (1) into parts -- you want to create a list of tables in each database, and then search each table. 
As for (2), you can write this yourself once you've done (1) `;-p`

Comment: You may need to check this [How to schedule a MySQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621355/how-to-schedule-a-mysql-query)

Comment: I am still a bit unclear on this, is there any example code?